# Bias and variance calculation for Ridge estimator of β

Tags: regression, linear-regression, variance, multicollinearity

I understand how bias and variance for ridge estimator of β are calculated when the model is **Y**=**X**β + ϵ. 
But I have the model **Y**=**X**<sup>t</sup>β + ϵ. I don't understand if a model like that makes sense, can someone help me with that? If it does, how to derive the bias and variance for ridge estimator of β?

Thanks!